# How to display and update user data from API using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I am trying to figure out why my react form fields aren't updating based on user input. They are blank. Wondering how to set the data coming from the API in props so fields.email gets populated correctly. And that any user input would change its value, so that they can be updated. Here is my sample code:

```
export default function User(props) {

api_data = props.data


const [fields, handleFieldChange] = useFormFields({});


return (
    <div>
      <input
        id="emailAddress"
        label="Email"
        onChange={handleFieldChange}
        value={fields.emailAddress}
      />
    </div>
);

function useFormFields(initialState) {
  const [fields, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  return [
    fields,
    function (event) {
      setValues({
        ...fields,
        [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
      });
    },
  ];
}
}
```

Comment: I think your code example is incomplete.  You have a return but it isn't inside any function scope...

Comment: Just updated to make it more clear @AlexanderNied

Comment: Why don't you pass the props to the initial props ? like `const [fields, handleFieldChange] = useFormFields(api_data);` That would set the initial props

Comment: I figured out my issue. It was with the parent component rendering the child before the API returned. I just added a isLoading condition in the parent component to only render the child if !isLoading. Thanks to everyone who commented!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured out your issue!  If it was caused by a simple typo, you can probably go ahead and delete this question.  If the solution might be helpful to others, then you can post it as an answer to this question and select it as correct.